# what is the difference between snort alert and snort log rule action?

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

[**] [1:2002973:1] Sample alert [**] - Alert Message
msg "sample message" - Log Message

Both are messages. What is the difference between these messages ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two actions you mention do the following:

- **alert** Generates an alert then logs the packet
- **log** Just logs the packet (doesn't generate an alert)

The alert is a very simple overview of the event whereas the log is generally more detailed and contains a packet dump too.

Documentation for the rule actions can be found [here](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node29.html)